# blockchain payment system, cant get it to work

Tags: php, api, bitcoin, blockchain

Callback:

```
<?php 
$id =""; 
$pw = "";

$secret = "f8fe526080ec3366eddbb498c6df4e1a"; //md5 hash a unui cuvant 
$address = "1MBF4cGmVac3r561YYRcamqJKN269yk7aD";

if($_GET['secret'] != $secret){ 
echo "Invalid"; 
return; 
} 

if($_GET['mainaddress'] != $address){ 
echo "Invalid"; 
return; 
} 
if (!isset($_GET['btc'])){ 
echo "Invalid"; 
return; 
} 
if (!isset($_GET['value'])){ 
echo "Invalid"; 
return; 
} 

$price = $_GET['btc']; 
$value= $_GET['value'] / 10000000;

if ($price >= $value){ 
$email = "email@yahoo.com"; 
$subject = "Payment Received"; 
$body = "Payment received for invoice #". $_GET['invoice'] . "\r\n" . "Price: " . $price . " BTC" . "\r\n"; 
$headers = "From: GoBets <sales@gobets.pw>". "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

$mail = mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);

}else{ 
$mail2 = mail($email, "rekt","hdhdhd",$headers); 
}

if($mail){ 
echo "*ok*"; // return code pentru blockchain 
}

if ($mail2){ 
echo "*ok*"; 
} 


?>
```

The way im creating an address and setting the callback url:

```
<?php
session_start();
$secret = "f8fe526080ec3366eddbb498c6df4e1a";   //md5 hash a unui cuvant
$address = "1MBF4cGmVac3r561YYRcamqJKN269yk7aD";  

if ($_GET['test'] == true) {
      echo 'Ignoring Test Callback';
      return;
   }

if(isset($_GET['key'])) {


if ($_GET['key'] == "p1"){
$price_in_usd = 1;
} elseif($_GET['key'] =="p2"){
$price_in_usd = 4.5;
} elseif($_GET['key'] =="p3"){
$price_in_usd = 8;
} elseif($_GET['key'] =="p4"){
$price_in_usd = 15;
}elseif($_GET['key'] == "test"){
$price_in_usd = 0.3;
}else{
echo "Invalid param. Please contact an administrator or try again later";
}

if ($price_in_usd <> ""){

$price_in_btc = file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=" . $price_in_usd);
$invoice = $_SESSION['s_ID'] . "-" . rand();
$callback = "http://gobets.pw/purchase/callback.php?invoice=".$invoice."&secret=".$secret."&mainaddress=".$address ."&btc=" . $price_in_btc;
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&address=".$address."&callback=" .urlencode($callback)), true);
$qrcode = "https://blockchain.info/qr?data=bitcoin:". $result["input_address"]. "?amount=" . $price_in_btc;
echo '<div align="center">';
echo '<img src="'.$qrcode.'"' . 'height="125" width="125"/>' . "</br>";
echo "Invoice #: " . $invoice . "<br>";
echo "Please send <b>" . $price_in_btc ."</b> BTC to <b>".  $result["input_address"] . "</b></br>";
echo "</div>";
}
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
}
?>
```

Nothing is happening when im sending money to the generated address except blockchain sending that amount back to my main address. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, i worked on blockchain api couple of times, i can say it works pretty fine. Which bitcoin address are you trying to send, and does that bitcoin address actually exists?

Comment: yes. im creating an address, send the money to it and then wait for a response from my website which never comes. but blockchain sends that amount of btc from the newly created address to my main address

Comment: Remember that call back from blockchain comes after many hours sometimes.

Comment: do you think my script is alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was actually the `callback.php` script.
I was checking for this:

```
if ($price >= $value)
```

which basically means:

```
if price to be paid > price paid then payment is succesful
```

which was wrong, lmao. I changed it to:

```
if ($value >= $price)
```

and now its working.